# Что я должен сделать чтобы спрашивался ввод и на основе данного ввода выводилось сообщение P.S С#

Tags: c#

```
                Console.WriteLine("Pleace enter u age");
                age = Console.ReadLine();

                int x = age;

                if (x > 18)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nice");
                }

                else if (age < 18)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GoodBye");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: P.S ошибки такие : Не удаеться не явно преоброзовать тип string в int , Оператор "<" Невозможно применить к операнду типа  "Int" и "String"

Comment: `int x = int.Parse(age);`

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
using System;

namespace HelloApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите свое имя: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Привет {name}");

            Console.ReadKey();//При нажатии любой клавиши программа заканчивается.
        }
    }
}
```

Получится:
Введите свое имя: Том
Привет Том

В вашем примере нужно добавить:

```
int intAge=Convert.ToInt32(age);
....
else 
if (intAge < 18)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GoodBye");
                }
```

плюс сделать проверку входной строки на формат:

```
private static readonly char RazdelitelRadradov = '.';
private static readonly char[] snumbers = new char[12] { '-', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', RazdelitelRadradov };
public bool TestStr(string arg1)
        {
            if ((arg1.Length == 0) || (arg1.IsNullOrEmpty()))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {

                bool bret = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < arg1.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!(snumbers.Contains(arg1[i])))
                    {
                        bret = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        bret = true;
                }
                return bret;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Надо перевод в int сделать. Я дописал в ответе. И использовать не age, а intAge

Comment: пишет что conver не содержит определение для Toint

Comment: Convert.ToInt32();

Comment: К чему тут `плюс сделать проверку входной строки на формат:`? Да и какой то он бредовый (ИМХО). Не проще `if (int.TryParse(value, out int x)) { /* делаем нужное с x */ }`, автору вопроса этого будет вполне достаточно.

Comment: Или так... Проверку входной строки, мало ли, юзер не то введёт. Там age string